# Symfony2 Form component - Adding fields from different Form Types

Tags: php, symfony

See the code example below:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('firstname');
    $builder->add('lastname');
    $builder->add('QualificationGradeOne'); // from Qualification Model
    // show some more user info
    $builder->add('address1');
    $builder->add('address2');
    $builder->add('QualificationGradeTwo'); // from Qualification Model
    /* ... */
```

This isnt my actual code. I've just shown it this way so that everyone understands my problem without knowing exactly the database structure etc of my application.

Does anyone know how to do this so that I can add one field of the `Qualification` model, then a few more `User` components, then adding a further few `Qualification` components. I've looked at creating a `Qualification Form Type`, however that returns back components all together and not individually.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$builder->add('gradeone', new QualificationGradeOne());
```